# Iterating over first half a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to iterate over first half of dictionary in python

This iterates over all values in the dictionary

```
for key, value in checkbox_dict.iteritems():
    print key,value
```

But I want to iterate over the first half of the dictionary only.

one way is to do it like this

```
for key, value in dict(checkbox_dict.items()[:11]).iteritems():
    print key,value
```

Is there any better way also ?

Comment: What do you mean by half a dictionary? Can you please clarify with an example?

Comment: Which half would you like to iterate over?

Comment: Remember that dictionaries are **unordered**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice the `dict.iteritems` iterator, unlike `dict.items()` with slice this won't create an intermediate list in memory.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> d = dict.fromkeys('abcdefgh')
>>> for k, v in islice(d.iteritems(), len(d)/2):
    print k, v
...     
a None
c None
b None
e None
```

Note that normal dictionaries are unordered, so the items are returned in arbitrary order.

Comment: Careful to use `d.items()` and `len(d)//2` in python3.X instead of `d.iteritems()` and `len(d)/2` which gives a float in python2.X

Answer (score 3):

If you mean: over half of the *items* here's a way:

```
for key, value in checkbox_dict.items()[:int(len(checkbox_dict)/2)]:
    pass
```

… But be aware: the elements in a normal dictionary don't necessarily keep the same iteration order that was used for inserting the elements … unless you use an `OrderedDict`.